# coordinates called from JSON not appearing

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, mapkit

I'm trying to display pins from my JSON file and they are not appearing any help would be greatly appreciated: also buttons will be calling separate JSON pages.

```
my code for mapview.m:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://w1281595.users.ecs.westminster.ac.uk/shops.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSArray *shoparray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         
NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation;                       

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in shoparray)
{
        location.longitude = [dictionary[@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        location.latitude = [dictionary[@"Latitude"] doubleValue];

        newAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        newAnnotation.title = dictionary[@"Name"];
        newAnnotation.coordinate = location;      

    }

    [self.mapview addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
```

Comment: Have you checked if `data` isn't coming `nil`?

Comment: It shouldn't is not the same as it isn't.

Comment: Have you tried to print both `shoparray` and `error` using `NSLog`?

Comment: it just threw an error

Comment: @AttilaKal-ElEgemensoy ur url is not returning anything,i mean its null

Comment: Dude,once open it in the browser,and see..

Comment: i see what you mean the university urls always want login need to setup a localhost i think

Answer (score 0):

Your loop creates a `newAnnotation` each time through. And then you add an array called `newAnnotations` to the map. But you've forgotten to put anything into the `newAnnotations` array.